# Showing a region on Google Maps?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, dictionary

I am doing a map-oriented app for a golf game. In that I have to show areas like green, sand and hazards. I think using the coordinates of that area, we will show. Any other idea to show such areas on Google maps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only plotting one or two regions, then good old-fashioned
[Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons) should work just fine.

(if they are big, using encoded polylines might save a bit; see just
up the page on the above link)

Answer (score 1):

Two other options (other than the native google maps polygon) are:
KmlLayer 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers
and 
FusionTablesLayer
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables

Both render the data as tiles, so will have better performance if there are lots of them
Both allow you to add click listeners and to display infowindows on clicks (if you need that)
Both can use kml formated data, there are lots of GIS tools that will create kml, including Google's MyPlaces, the Google Maps tool.